# Combining two webassembly components programmed in different high-level languages

Tags: java, c++, webassembly

Lets say, two developers (A and B) are developing different components for one application. The end-result is in webassembly.

However, A uses Java and TeaVm (lets say) to get the final result in webassembly. B uses C++ and converts it to webassembly.

Is it possible to have their work integrated together into one webassembly program (the same way you would merge different class files in Java into one jar file) ? If yes, how would that be done ? If no, why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic interoperability between different compilers targeting Wasm. Both compilers would have to define and agree upon a common ABI for WebAssembly. In fact, that is the case even when both compile the same source language. The situation is really no different from that of compilers targeting machine code.